# Dijkstra's algorithm confusion

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

I have this graph:

[image]

and I am trying to apply Djiktra's algorithm to find the shortest path from A to E.

Here is my progress:

[image]

However I havent understood what I have found.Okay I have some values for A,B,C,D,E but how does that help me find the shortest path from A to E? And what about the last step?I havent done the last step because I didnt know what to do.(E isnt written out from the unvisited nodes).How should I continue?

Comment: You did it correctly, the shortest distance from A to E is 6, if you want to recover the path then you need to store a little bit of extra information, every time you update the distances, if you change a value you need to record which vertex was used to change the value. So for vertex $E$ you would store $B$, for vertex $B$ you would store $C$ and for $C$ you would store $A$, so you are able to recover the path $E,B,C,A$ by going back from $E$.